# Should radio buttons be enclosed within the label tags?

Tags: html, radio-button

They both seem to work. However, contrary to what I originally thought... FreeCodeCamp seems to be recommending that radio buttons should be placed WITHIN the label tags!

```
<label for="indoor">
   <input id="indoor" type="radio" name="indoor-outdoor"> Indoor
</label>
```

Whereas, other sites seem to suggest that the following is more standard compliant.

```
<input id="indoor" type="radio" name="indoor-outdoor"> 
<label for="indoor">Indoor</label>
```

So, who's right?

Comment: Both are right, but if you put the control inside the `label` you don't need the `for` attribute

Comment: Yes. I already mentioned that they both work... But I am trying to figure out which one is more standards complaint.

Comment: Apologies - you threw me with the use of the question "who's right"